# Why IntelliJ does not show errors in java code?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to configure intelliJ to disply errors in java code like eclipse?
see the screenshot[image]

Comment: What errors? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: no junit package is missed

Comment: Yes this is the problem. eclipse shows that junit package is missing but intellij does not show any errors on the editor

Comment: Then perhaps the issue is with your Eclipse project setup.

Comment: No. Junit is missing in fact but IntelliJ does not indicate this.

Comment: +1 for paintbrush skillz.

Answer (score 2):

It does show the errors you expect, *if* you don't have the JUnit jar files in the classpath.

I created the exact same file as you showed in my IntelliJ and it really shows the errors:

[image]

What you might have done is that you have probably accidentally added the jar to the classpath.

Check the `External Libraries` as you can see in the picture. If there is no JUnit there, then it really is missing.

Now I can easily add the JUnit jar from IntelliJ and you'll notice the difference in the `External Libraries`:

[image]

Here it has been added under `External Libraries` and the error goes away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly already included the `junit` library into your IntelliJ project configuration.

This is easy to do, since IntelliJ has a quick action (alt-enter) to `Add junit to classpath`.

Look in `Settings` -> Libraries / Global Libraries and you will see it there. :)

Or you can look directly in `Settings` on the relevant Module -> Dependencies

Either that, or the project you are working in is configured already (perhaps via maven?) to have a junit dependency.